Carousel in Angular Issue
I'm trying to create a simple Carousel in Angular but the interaction part doesn't work , I didn't figure out the issue, can someone help me pls?
When clicking on buttons they don't change the different pictures..
I tried to use ChatGpt and it doesn't help that much ..
I'm expecting to make the interaction part work...
This is the code :
slideshow.component.html :
<body>
    <div id="carousel-container">
        <div *ngIf="  images && images.length > 0" class="carousel-container">
          <div *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index">
            <img [src]="image.imagesrc" [alt]="image.imagealt"
                 [ngClass]="{'image-active': selectedIndex === i}"
                 (click)="selectImage(i)" class="fade">
         
        </div>
          <div *ngIf="indicators" class="carousel-dot-container">
            <span class="dot" *ngFor="let dot of images; let i = index"
                  [ngClass]="{'dot-active': selectedIndex === i}"
                  (click)="selectImage(i)">
            </span>
          </div>
          <a class="prev" (click)="previousSlide()">&#10094;</a>
          <a class="next" (click)="nextSlide()">&#10095;</a>
          
        </div>
    
      </div>

</body>
</html>  ,



slideshow.component.ts
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {  CommonModule } from '@angular/common'; 

interface SlideContent{
   imagesrc: string;
   imagealt: string;
   
}



@Component({
  selector: 'app-slideshow',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './slideshow.component.html',
  styleUrl: './slideshow.component.css'
})
export class SlideshowComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() images: SlideContent[] = [];
  @Input() indicators = true;

  selectedIndex = 0;
   intervalId:any;

ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log('Slideshow initialized with images:', this.images);
}

//sets index of image on dot/indicator click
selectImage(index: number): void{

this.selectedIndex= index;
}


startAutoSlide() {
  this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    this.nextSlide();
  }, 3000); // Change slide every 3 seconds
}

nextSlide() {
  this.selectedIndex = (this.selectedIndex + 1) % this.images.length;
}

previousSlide() {
  this.selectedIndex = (this.selectedIndex - 1 + this.images.length) % this.images.length;
}
}


App.component.ts
images =[
 {
    imagesrc:'example',
     imagealt:"example",
 },
 {
  imagesrc: 'example',
   imagealt:"example",
},
{
  imagesrc:'example',
   imagealt:"example",
},

 }

And then in App.component.html:
<app-slideshow [images]="images" [indicators]="true"></app-slideshow>
Error: NG0500: During hydration Angular expected  but found meta.

get rid of body and HTML tags, they belong in index.html never on components, thats causing the hydration error

So every html of every component don't need the structure?

html,`body`` tags belong on index.html, they can only be declared once! Since your angular app is created inside the body tag of index.html

ok,cool still getting the error.. I deleted all the html/body tags from the components and leave it on index.html .

then comment out the components one by one and identify the problem, but the below answer is the solution to your initial question!

The call to autoslide method, on ngOnInit hook was missing.
I added one more input parameter for autoplay to enable it!
Since you have SSR enabled, you can use the isPlatformBrowser to ensure the code runs only on the browser, since the server does not have document or window or setInterval
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log('Slideshow initialized with images:', this.images);
    if (this.isBrowser) {
      if (this.autoplay) {
        this.startAutoSlide();
      }
    }
  }

Full Code:
import { CommonModule, isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Inject, Input, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

interface SlideContent {
  imagesrc: string;
  imagealt: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slideshow',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  styles: [
    `
  .fade {
    display: none;
  }
  .image-active {
    display: block;
  }
  `,
  ],
  template: `
  @defer {
    <div id="carousel-container">
        <div *ngIf="  images && images.length > 0" class="carousel-container">
          <div *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index">
            <img [src]="image.imagesrc" [alt]="image.imagealt"
                 [ngClass]="{'image-active': selectedIndex === i}"
                 (click)="selectImage(i)" class="fade">
         
        </div>
          <div *ngIf="indicators" class="carousel-dot-container">
            <span class="dot" *ngFor="let dot of images; let i = index"
                  [ngClass]="{'dot-active': selectedIndex === i}"
                  (click)="selectImage(i)">
            </span>
          </div>
          <a class="prev" (click)="previousSlide()">&#10094;</a>
          <a class="next" (click)="nextSlide()">&#10095;</a>
          
        </div>
    
      </div>
  }
  `,
})
export class SlideShow {
  @Input() images: SlideContent[] = [];
  @Input() indicators = true;
  @Input() autoplay = true;

  selectedIndex = 0;
  intervalId: any;
  isBrowser = false;

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private _platformId: Object) {
    this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this._platformId);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log('Slideshow initialized with images:', this.images);
    if (this.isBrowser) {
      if (this.autoplay) {
        this.startAutoSlide();
      }
    }
  }

  //sets index of image on dot/indicator click
  selectImage(index: number): void {
    this.selectedIndex = index;
  }

  startAutoSlide() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      this.nextSlide();
    }, 3000); // Change slide every 3 seconds
  }

  nextSlide() {
    this.selectedIndex = (this.selectedIndex + 1) % this.images.length;
  }

  previousSlide() {
    this.selectedIndex =
      (this.selectedIndex - 1 + this.images.length) % this.images.length;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [SlideShow],
  template: `
    <app-slideshow [images]="images" [indicators]="true"></app-slideshow>
  `,
})
export class App {
  images = [
    {
      imagesrc: 'https://placehold.co/600x400/000000/FFFFFF/png?text=Slide+1',
      imagealt: 'example',
    },
    {
      imagesrc: 'https://placehold.co/600x400/000000/FFFFFF/png?text=Slide+2',
      imagealt: 'example',
    },
    {
      imagesrc: 'https://placehold.co/600x400/000000/FFFFFF/png?text=Slide+3',
      imagealt: 'example',
    },
  ];
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

I'm getting a timeout error ..btw thanks for the answer

@NOne updated my answer again! try now!

I'm having like a tiny problem... when i do changes , it stays on building the project for an infinite time and everytime i need to restart the cmd .

@NOne please try my code with isBrowser

So when I delete the import zone.js it works , but setInterval no.. what can I do?

@NOne please create a new question and share the GitHub repo
